# How to print to javascript console in Pycharm/Intellij

Tags: javascript, pycharm

Given a tiny web page that includes

```
console.log('hello ..')
```

in it: we can see the output on chrome developer tools | console

[image]

However it does not show up on the `Pycharm` `console`:

[image]

So then: how to make it show up in `pycharm` -  is that possible?  If not then what actually *is* that console for?

Comment: When a browser starts parsing HTML, it  executes javascript scripts  and  console logs to a developer console( if specified to do so) that is a part of a browser. Your Pycharm console has nothing to do with a browser parsing HTML. You can execute js scripts in console  with node.js and see output in that console.

Comment: aha - so server side js output goes there. thx. care to make answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a browser starts parsing HTML, it executes javascript scripts and console logs to a developer console( if specified to do so) that is a part of a browser. Your Pycharm console has nothing to do with a browser parsing HTML. You can execute js scripts in console with node.js and see output in that console.